# How to avoid deadlock on @synchronized(self)?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, synchronization, deadlock

I have some synchronization in my Objective-C project. The code looks like this:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    //some code
    @synchronized(self) {    //at this line deadlocks
        //some code
    }
    //some code
}
```

and on this line (`@synchronized`), a deadlock always occurs. I can also tell that this delegate method is called very often.

How do I avoid such deadlocks?

Comment: What for are you using `@synchronized(self)`?

Comment: I'm using this for accessing shared variable, for example default value or data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your lock from another thread never releases the lock acquired by `@synchronized(self)` -- you're probably waiting for something to finish, which is happening on another thread, trying to access the lock while held from another point. Look for this problem (if you pause, you will probably see waiting in the debugger on another thread). This also suggests your locks are held for long periods - only hold them for short periods if you want to use concurrency effectively.

Comment: Thank you very much Justin! Yes, you are right, this delegate method calls another thread where I'm using also locks. I changed to @synchronized(someVariable) and it seems resolved partially issue, but also happens some time.

Comment: It's not right solution, you just ignoring problem. See my answer below.

Comment: @igelekle ok - so just figure out how you can break that (co)dependency, while keeping it threadsafe. holding a lock for a long time should also be avoided. adjusting the granularity also helps (as you have attempted, from the looks of the update) -- big, high level locks which protect a lot of data are often killers (too many tiny ones can also hurt).

Comment: Thanks Justin, okey. Sometimes it's so hard to figure out why it occurs.

Comment: @igelekle you're welcome. some threading issues can be very hard to reproduce. correct concurrency is a huge subject. if it's not 100% safe, it is unsafe. sometimes, you just have to break it down into smaller, more manageable pieces to visualize how your data must be protected. concurrency as an afterthought can be very time consuming to rectify.

Comment: okey, Justin. That's what I will do. It's only occurs when I scroll  a table very fast, and all of the table items must be refreshed with new data, each refresh of the table item fire the new thread. That's why this delegate method is called very often.

Comment: hmm - it's usually not good to create threads all over the place. you may want to try an `NSOperationQueue` approach (with a reasonably low max operation count) which does not require long blocking calls.

Comment: Yes, I mean NSOperation. I have NSOperationQueue, then create NSOperation, set max concurrent operations to 10. Thats why I'm using @synchronized(self) - for accessing operation queue and creating operation.

Answer (score 3):

You should review your classes design hardly. It shouldn't happen.
If it happens, look at any critical sections (synchronized()) that locks the instance. One of them lock your instance forever. Or, maybe, you have cross lock (Method M1 locks A, and method M2 locks B, and they want to swap locking simultaneously ), it causes deadlock.

Comment: Thank you! I need to redesign functionality.